flutter web loading canvaskit locally
Hope you're coding well.
I am building flutter web app and need to be able to run it on local network with canvaskit build.
A web request is sent to gstatic on initialization of web app from client side.
When not connected to internet the response fails to fetch canvaskit.js
How can I make my app get this file from local server so the app can run without the need of internet.
I have added the following lines to my index.html file and still requests for canvaskit.js:
  <script>
    window.flutterConfiguration = {
      canvasKitBaseUrl: "/canvaskit/"
    };
  </script>
 <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
          let config = {
          canvasKitVariant: "full",
        };
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine(config).then(function (appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

and I have tried building web app with the following commands:
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
flutter build web  --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true --web-renderer canvaskit 
flutter build web --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=./canvaskit.js --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true --web-renderer canvaskit
flutter build web --base-href "/" --no-web-resources-cdn --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true --web-renderer canvaskit

my flutter doctor is:
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.4046], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.34)
    X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete.
      Please use Visual Studio Installer to complete the installation or reinstall Visual Studio.
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[!] Network resources
    X A network error occurred while checking "https://maven.google.com/": The semaphore timeout period has expired.


! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

I managed to load canvaskit from local files but the following syntax error occurs in canvaskit.js 97:504
the following line consists of:
var gb=0,ib=0,jb="undefined"!=typeof TextDecoder?new TextDecoder("utf8"):void 0,kb=(a,b,c)=>{var d=b+c;for(c=b;a[c]&&!(c>=d);)++c;if(16<c-b&&a.buffer&&jb)return jb.decode(a.subarray(b,c));for(d="";b<c;){var f=a[b++];if(f&128){var k=a[b++]&63;if(192==(f&224))d+=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXf)}return d},

Can you guys help please. Thanks in advance.

Did you find a solution to this? Would be interested in it.

Well it was because of firewall set on the server what I did to solve is pretty simple:
I used following to build the app:
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --no-web-resources-cdn
this ensures that you request does not go to gstatic instead it uses canvaskit serving on local server
the syntax error was fixed by replacing canvaskit.js files in built files with obfuscated files (you can use online tools to obfuscate those files) this ensures that firewall won't touch your code as it did for me.
feel free to email me for more help. :)
@LoadJulz

Hello. I just built Flutter with "flutter build web -t lib/main.dart --web-renderer canvaskit --no-web-resources-cdn" as suggested. But file "flutter_bootstrap.js" still wants to access "https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/edd8456..." both for canvaskit.js and then for canvaskit.wasm. Still not working

Hey @Jemolah do you see canvaskit directory after building web app? my suggestion is you also add canvaskit directory to your indes.html as a script Let me find the syntax for that and tell you on next comment.


Just edit the index.html as this:
<!-- replace this -->
<!-- <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script> -->

<!-- with this -->
<script>
  {{flutter_js}}
  {{flutter_build_config}}

  _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
    onEntrypointLoaded: async function (engineInitializer) {
      let appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine({
        // JsFlutterConfiguration goes here...
        canvasKitBaseUrl: "/canvaskit/",
      });
      appRunner.runApp();
    },
  });
</script>

References:

Flutter web app initialization documentation provides the custom bootstrap script template.

Source code of flutter engine's configuration indicates that window.flutterConfiguration is now deprecated.


